# Making a native library for Java that uses fftw3

Tags: java, c++, fftw, java-native-interface

I want to call a native `cpp` library that uses `fftw3` from java. My java class is the following:

```
/* FourierGui.java */
public class FourierGui {
    native void fourierFromC();
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("fourier");
    }
    static public void main(String argv[]) {
        FourierGui ft = new FourierGui();
        ft.fourierFromC();
    }
}
```

My `cpp` library is

```
/* fourier.cpp */

#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include "fftw3.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_FourierGui_fourierFromC (JNIEnv * env, jobject jobj) {

    // something that uses fftw3

}
```

and I create the lybrary with:

```
g++ -o libfourier.so -shared fourier.cpp -lc
```

But when I run the java class with

```
java -Djava.library.path="/path/to/lib/" FourierGui
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/red/Scrivania/JNI/libfourier.so: /path/to/lib/libfourier.so: undefined symbol: fftw_plan_dft_1d
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1880)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
    at FourierGui.<clinit>(FourierGui.java:10)
```

I also try to add the path to `libfftw3.so` in `java.library.path` but I get the same error. It seems that it can't find this last library.. (if I compile and run the `cpp` code by itself it works with no error...)

I know there are java wrappers for fftw3 but I would like to do this by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it... I have to link the `fftw3` library when compiling the `cpp` file:

```
g++ -o libfourier.so -shared fourier.cpp -lc -lfftw3
```